# What would the assembly name be for Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I wanted to dynamically load classes in C#. I remember in Java we used `Class.forname("String")` , so after googling I found out that we could use `Activator.CreateInstance` in C# . I cannot figure out what my assembly name would be here. Any suggestions ?

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly","namespaceA.SomeClassName");
```

Comment: If object is in the same assembly where you are writing the code pass the first parameter as `null` beacuse in that case the executing assembly is searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply the name of the assembly. That *might* be the same as the namespace, but it might not. For example, the [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345746.aspx) class is in the `System.Core` assembly (in `System.Core.dll`).

If the target assembly is a framework one, look at the documentation.

If it's one that's under your control, you should know the assembly name - it's part of the project properties.

Comment: The simplest way to find the assembly a type is defined in is to select it in the code editor and press F12 (view definition).  If the class was an framework class, the first line of the Metadata shown will include the assembly name.